# Specific YARN Node not spawning containers

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

Running Terasort on a cluster that has 4 "slave" nodes (DataNode and NodeManagers co-located). It spawns containers in all the other nodes but it, doesn't spawn containers on one node, and if it does, it only spawns up to 6-8 containers only.

- 2GB Mappers
- 4GB Reducers
- 48vCores
- 180GB per Node

I found out that the specific node has a decommissioned data node, so I recommissioned it. Aside from that, there's nothing else I could see on why the YARN RM is not spawning containers on that specific node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

Recommissioned Data Node won't run jobs on it because the blocks there are "old ones" due to a manual "data node directory" copy-paste procedure. Recreated the files there.